# What tenses should these sentences be?

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, verbs, past-tense, present-tense

> How **do** they exchange their languages in the past when we all didn’t have any dictionary ?

And

> How **did** they exchange their languages in the past when we all didn’t have any dictionary ?

And these as well

> Whatever has even happened just for a last second that **is** the past

And

> Whatever has even happened just for a last second that **was** the past

Please explain me about it in detail I’m so confused.

Comment: What is it that is leading you to think that the present tense should be used for a past event?

Answer (score 0):

None of these sentences are grammatically correct. I have tried to correct them, but I have had to use some assumptions that may not be correct.

For the first pair of sentences:

1/ we are talking about what happened in the past, so we use 'did' not 'do'.

2/ I am not exactly sure what you mean by 'exchange their languages', but I am assume this means 'learn each others' language'.

3/ I am assuming that when you say 'they' and 'we' in these sentences, you are talking about the same group of people. If that is the case you should either use the third party plural ('they') in both places, or the first party plural ('we') in both places. In this case, I will assume that 'they' should be used.

4/ I am not sure what you mean by 'we all'. In English we can say 'We all had a dictionary', but we would never say, 'We all didn't have a dictionary'. Instead, we would say, 'None of us had a dictionary', or 'We didn't have any dictionaries'. Or, in this case, because we are changing 'we' to 'they', we would say, 'None of them had a dictionary' or 'They didn't have any dictionaries'.

5/ In my opinion, this sentence would read better if the phrase 'in the past' is moved to the beginning of the sentence instead of the middle. This is a matter of personal style, not grammar.

So, I would change you sentence to:

> In the past, how did they learn each others' language when they didn’t have any dictionaries?

or

> In the past, how did they learn each others' language when none of them had a dictionary?

For the second pair of sentences:

1/ The phrase 'just for a last second' is not standard English. I think it would be better to replace it with either, 'in the last second' or 'just a second ago'. If you wish to stress how recently in the past that time was, you could use 'even' and say, 'even in the last second' or 'even just a second ago'.

2/ Moving 'even' to this new position allows us to remove it from within the present perfect phrase 'has happened'. I do not mean that the present perfect should never be split, this has always been permissible, especially with an adverb; but some splits look and sound better than others.

3/ The phrase 'that is the past' can be used in English, but it is more idiomatic to say 'is in the past'.  Again, if you want to emphasise that something which happened just a second ago is now in the past, you could say 'is already in the past'.

So, I would change your sentence to:

> Whatever has happened, even just a second ago, is already in the past.

I think that 'is' is the correct verb to use here because 'has happened' is in the present perfect tense, so we are focussing on how a past event has present consequences.

If we change the present perfect to the past perfect (or simple past tense) then 'was' would be the correct verb to use. E.g.

> Whatever had happened, even just a second ago, was already in the past.

or

> Whatever happened, even just a second ago, was already in the past.